# SSIS - Script task: Replace TEXT in text file using VBscript with dynamic file path

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, ssis

I am using SSIS script task to replace text in text file. In my VB script hard coded file path in script but I want to use user variable instead.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO, objFile, strText, strNewText

objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Text.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close()
strNewText = Replace(strText, "Jim", "James")

objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Text.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine(strNewText)
objFile.Close()
objFSO = Nothing
objFile = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @Alex's answer to add and reference variables.  But just an FYI that you can do your entire script in 2 lines of code if you use System.IO.

so add this to the imports section

```
Import System.IO
```

Then use these lines in your MAIN Sub

```
Dim filePath As String = Dts.Variables("User::FullFilePath").Value.ToString()
File.WriteAllText(filePath, File.ReadAllText(filePath).Replace("Jim", "James"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your customer variables to the [task script] in tab **Script** using **ReadOnlyVariables** and/or **ReadWriteVariables**, after having defined the variables globally; take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

More in detail: 
to add variables to your project you can select the [Variables] tab in the upper left in the Package, than insert requirend fields:

[image]

Variables can be added to the [task script] by selecting them as ReadOnlyVariables and/or ReadWriteVariables:

[image]

so you can use within the [task script] by declaring: 
**Dts.Variables("User::Variable").Value**

*as @Matt says online documentation omits 'User::'*

Comment: I would only note that I have had issues when I don't use the "USER::" identifier e.g. Dts.Variables("User::VariableName").Value method which I know is weird because of Microsoft's documentation say you shouldn't have to use it....  @M.Mehta getting an error doesn't give Alex or the community any details of what could possible be wrong you should update your post with the details of your current attempt and the error.

Comment: Matt, I don't get you exactly what you are trying to say. I found few VB scripts that written with User variables but not for replace text in file of course. So I am trying to figure out how this script will be work if I want to use Use variables instead of hard coded path!!

Comment: Thanks to Alex and Matt.