# SSIS load XML Invalid character in the given encoding

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding, ssis

I'm using SQL Server 2014\SSIS.

I have a C# script task that loads XML data from a 3rd party XML file that has been working.  Recently it has been failing stating:

```
Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 201, position 169.
```

Using breakpoints, the following C# line is when the error is generated:

```
XMLDataset.ReadXml(XMLFileNameWithPath);
```

fyi - XMLFileNameWithPath is a local variable that I pass the XML filename to.

When I open the XML file in Notepadd++ and go to Line 201\position 169, it appears the character 'ñ' is the culprit.

The first line of the XML states it is in UTF 8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: This article seems to suggest that you replace characters with unicode. https://support.crossref.org/hc/en-us/articles/215652783-Special-characters-in-your-XML. So before you convert to XML, replace it.

Comment: SSIS has XML Source Adapter. Please give it a shot instead of Script Task/Component.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I cannot use the native SSIS XML Source - the XML file contains 50 output columns, that would mean 50 output tables and then trying to work out how to join them. And I don't fancy the Merge Join component - 50 times in the data flow

Comment: Michael, the fact, that you can read `encoding="UTF-8"` does not mean, that the file really is utf-8 encoded. You might try to take the declaration away (the part with `<?xml blah blah?>`) and let the system decide. And it might help, to open the file in a smart editor (such as notepad++)  to check the real encoding (and maybe to change this).

Comment: @Shnugo If I open in Notepadd ++ it does indeed state it is UTF-8.  The XML file is coming from a 3rd party - are you suggesting performing a find\replace on the XML before I then load it?

Comment: @Michael depending on the version sql server's support for utf8 was very limited. Don't know about ssis... I think, that v2014 sp2 introduced utf8 for bulk loads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a Script Task to pre-process the XML file prior to loading to change the encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.  This now loads and I no longer receive the encoding error.

Credit due where credit deserved I am using the find and replace as detailed here - although it states text file it works with a XML file:

[SSIS - Script task: Replace TEXT in text file using VBscript with dynamic file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492413/ssis-script-task-replace-text-in-text-file-using-vbscript-with-dynamic-file-p)