# how to write vb script using replace() function?

Tags: ssis

I read the example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492413/ssis-script-task-replace-text-in-text-file-using-vbscript-with-dynamic-file-p).

But it returns the error, how to solve the error?

[image]

Comment: *I read the example in here.* This is C# example. Whereas you use SSIS. Look [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're missing an import statement at the top of your code.

As mentioned in [These Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8) which show that the method you're calling is present in `System.IO` and in your [linked answer/post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496125/7226895) you're likely missing the top part of the answer you seem to have copied.

Quote

> so add this to the imports section

```
Import System.IO
```